# I side loaded an apk game which now asks me to update but I don't know how to do that. Please help. I have three games now wanting updates. Thanks. AB

Tags: apk, side-loading

I side loaded some games on my Android phone and all are now asking for updates. What do I do?  I cannot get past the update screen.

Comment: Where did you get the game in the first place? Go back there and grab an updated version.

Comment: Thank you Andy. I tried that and it worked. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a newer APK file from the same place you got the original one. Install this new APK the same way you did originally, and it will replace the older version.

Note that the signature on the old and new versions have to match, so if your original APK file was a modified version, instead of the version released by the publisher, you can't update it to the official version or to a version modified by somebody different. In that case, you need to uninstall the old version and then install the new version, and you'll lose all the app's data and settings.